Fluorination of PCl5 in polar organic solvent

The species formed on fluorination of phosphorus pentachloride in a polar organic solve are

While researching this question, I managed to find this in the book: N. N. Greenwood and A. Earnshaw, Book: Chemistry of Elements, 2nd Edition, Butterworh-Heinemann publication, 1988(reprint), Ch-12, pp.499.
This confirms the option B, but I was unable to find anything regarding formation of compound given in option A. It would be much appreciated if anyone could provide a source which proves that option A is correct as well.

The correct option is (B). I got the exact reaction statement from here1:

Interestingly, fluorination of $\ce{PCl5}$ in polar solvent yield ionic isomers such as $\ce{[PCl4]+[PCl4F2]-}$ and $\ce{[PCl4]+[PF6]-}$.

The reaction is more elaborated here2:

Fluorination of the crystalline pentachloride results initially in preferential attack of the octahedral anion, which contains the more loosely bound halogen. Further fluorination leads to the pentafluoride, but the tetrafluorophosphonium cation is formed in an unstable complex with $\ce{SbF5}$. It is less stable tham $\ce{NF4+}$
$$\ce{[PCl4]+[PCl6]- + 2AsF3 -> [PCl4]+[PF6]- + 2 AsCl3}$$
$$\ce{3[PCl4]+[PF6]- + 4AsF3 -> 6PF5 + 4AsCl3}$$
$$\ce{PF5 + 3SbF5 -> [PF4]+[Sb3F16]-}$$

Also must read: Why does F replace the axial bond in PCl5?
References

Inorganic Chemistry, PHI Learning Pvt. Ltd., 2012
Phosphorus: Chemistry, Biochemistry and Technology, D.E.C. Corbridge, Sixth Edition, 2013

